# Could not load file or assembly System.Reflection.TypeExtensions

Tags: visual-studio-2017, xunit

I got below exception while running xunit test projects which works under VS 2017 15.3

> [2017/12/4 23:08:40 Error] [xUnit.net 00:00:00.0033291] xxx.Test: Catastrophic failure: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Xunit.DiaSession' threw an exception. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Reflection.TypeExtensions, Version=4.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>      at Xunit.DiaSession..cctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      at Xunit.DiaSession..ctor(String assemblyFileName)
>      at Xunit.DiaSessionWrapper..ctor(String assemblyFilename)
>      at Xunit.XunitFrontController..ctor(AppDomainSupport appDomainSupport, String assemblyFileName, String configFileName, Boolean shadowCopy, String shadowCopyFolder, ISourceInformationProvider sourceInformationProvider, IMessageSink diagnosticMessageSink)
>      at Xunit.Runner.VisualStudio.TestAdapter.VsTestRunner.RunTestsInAssembly(IRunContext runContext, IFrameworkHandle frameworkHandle, LoggerHelper logger, IMessageSinkWithTypes reporterMessageHandler, AssemblyRunInfo runInfo)
>   My current VS 2017 version is 15.4.5.

I have tried the work around which has been provided previously, but none did not work. And I have try to downgrade my VS 2016 to 15.3, but I could not find the 15.3 package to install. I have tried to install xunit to latest version.
Any help would be appreciated.
Update:
Project Type:xUnit Test Project(.NET Core)
Target: net 461

Comment: What kind of project is it? What .NET version are you targeting? What dependencies are set? (Almost certainly you have a missing or wrongly versioned dependency.)

Comment: what do you mean by dependenceies?

Comment: Eg. NuGet packages used, including those used by other projects you reference.

Answer (score 6):

It seems VS 2017 fail to load specific "xunit.runner.visualstudio", after checking [VS2017 15.4.2 - Unable to run tests for projects targeting .NET Framework 4.6.x #1542](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1542) again, I deleted the "%TEMP%\VisualStudioTestExplorerExtensions", create a new Xunit project, change the nonworked.csproj xunit.runner.visualstudio from 2.2.0 to 2.3.1, it works now. Not sure why it did not work when I try it previous.
Hope it will help others.

Comment: Thanks. Updating from 2.2.0 to 2.3.1 worked for me too. If anyone is curious as to why it happens, [this link](https://github.com/xunit/xunit/issues/1348) outlines the problem pretty well.

Comment: Happened to me recently. Moving from v2.3.0 to v2.4.0 worked for me

Answer (score 2):

You need to install System.Reflection.TypeExtensions using  VS Package Manager using the following command:

**Install-Package System.Reflection.TypeExtensions -Version 4.5.1**

for more information please review the following link
[System.Reflection.TypeExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions/)